# AttributeError:'str' object has no attribute 'tk' inside a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a function open1 in tkinter to read csv files inside a directoy but at the moment to print out the results as labels in my window I'm getting: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'. I believe the error is in my label(root) but I have tried some other things and has found no answer. I would like to ask for help in this part of my code just as it is and not as a Class.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Results')
root.iconbitmap('aa.ico')
root.geometry("100x150")

def open1():
    path = (filedialog.askdirectory())
    v1.set(path)
    all_files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

    #Read the files in the path
    df_from_each_file = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files]

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, "."):
        for file in files:
            a = str(file)
            x = re.findall('^([^.]*).*', a)
            for i in df_from_each_file:
                for n in x:
                    r = "Result " + n + ": " + str(int(i['Result'].sum()))
            #print(results)
            label = Label(root, text = r).grid(row=i, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)


v1 = StringVar()
b1 = Button(root, text="File", command=open1)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=2 ,sticky=W)
searchfile1 = Entry(root, textvariable=v1, borderwidth=3)
searchfile1.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=140)
    
root.mainloop()
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:python\python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-38-8acd6f6c673f>", line 33, in open1
    labeli = Label(root, text = r)
  File "c:python\python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "c:python\python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2292, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "c:python\python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2262, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your `root` value in your loop through `os.walk`:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, "."):
```

Try calling it something different:

```
for root_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(path, "."):
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Also I would like to know how to create labels inside the for loop? or if necessary to use a counter to accomplish that? I mean to print it consecutive one by one in the window

Comment: @Richard21 There is no need for "counter". Just declare the labels in different positions and it should be fine. If this answer, helped you, make sure to mark it as the correct one

Comment: @Richard21 since that's a separate question, it's fine to post that on this site as a new question. In fact it's required that you not ask multiple separate questions in one post.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your comments.